# ¿Cómo puedo agregar la propiedad required de un select?

Tags: javascript, html

Soy nuevo en este tema, tengo un problemita, con esta funcion que copie, tengo este

```
<input type="checkbox" id="confirmodato" name="confirmodato" onclick="myFunction()" value="1" >
```

y que al checkear el usuario agrege la propiedad required a al siguente select

```
<select name="ciu" id="ciu" class="input">
<option selected="selected"> Seleccione su Ciudad </option>
....
</select>
```

tengo esta funcion javascript pero no me funciona

```
  function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("confirmodato");
 if (checkBox.checked == true){
     $('#ciu').prop("required", true);
  } else {
    
  }
  }
```

Alguien me puede ayudar por favor

Tambien prove esto

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("confirmodato");
 var ciu = document.getElementById('ciu');
  
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    ciu.attributes['required'] = 'required';
  } else {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Tienes algún error en la consola?

Comment: Si quieres agregar un atributo se hace con `elemento.setAttribute(nombreAtributo, valor)`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que agregas la propiedad `required` cuando se marca el checkbox, pero no la eliminas cuando se desmarca:

```
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("confirmodato");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    $('#ciu').prop("required", true);
  } else {
    // Aquí deberías quitar la propiedad
  }
}
```

Con *jQuery* no necesitas complicarte tanto; para empezar, no uses eventos en línea, es decir, dentro de la etiqueta `<input onclick="funcion()>` porque eso complica el mantenimiento de tus proyectos; mejor usa el método [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) para escuchar el evento que, en este caso, es mejor `change` para que se ejecute cada que haya modificación en el checkbox:

```js
// Escuchar cambios en el checkbox
$('#confirmodato').on('change', function() {
    // El valor de required es igual a la propiedad checked del checkbox
    $('#ciu').prop('required', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```css
/* Solo para ver que se aplica el required */
select:required {
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="confirmodato" name="confirmodato" value="1">

<select name="ciu" id="ciu" class="input">
    <option selected="selected"> Seleccione su Ciudad </option>
</select>
```

Con Javascript puro es prácticamente lo mismo, solo con algunas diferencias:

- Accedes al elemento con `document.querySelector()` en lugar de `$()`
- Asignas el evento con `.addEventListener()` en lugar de `.on()`
- Defines y accedes a las propiedades necesarias directamente, sin necesidad de `.prop()`

```js
document.querySelector('#confirmodato').addEventListener('change', function() {
    // El valor de required es igual a la propiedad checked del checkbox
    document.querySelector('#ciu').required = this.checked;
});
```

```css
/* Solo para ver que se aplica el required */
select:required {
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="confirmodato" name="confirmodato" value="1">

<select name="ciu" id="ciu" class="input">
    <option selected="selected"> Seleccione su Ciudad </option>
</select>
```